# Session values cant be obtained between two different web api calls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have two Web API methods called in different cases. I have used the **SetString** method and the value is set in method 1 but when the 2nd method is called for other cases, accessing the value using the **GetString** method it returns the value as null.

```
public string Method1(string args)
{
   HttpContext.Session.SetString("key", "value"); // value is set in this method.
}

public string Method2(string args)
{
   string value = HttpContext.Session.GetString("key"); // value is obtained as null here
}
```

Any suggestions to resolve this issue. I have added controller manually in the blazor server-side application for WebAPI call.

Comment: Hi. Came across a similar case today. Please check my updated answer. BR

Answer (score 1):

`options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None` must be used to allow cross-site cookie use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Startup#ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSession(options => {
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600); // 10 minutes
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;    
});
```

Startup#Configure

```
app.UseSession();
```

The order of middleware is important. Call UseSession after UseRouting and before UseEndpoints. See Middleware Ordering.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0

If you run your app on multiple instances, you'll need to choose a strategy. Storing sessions using Distributed Cache is preferable. More info: https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-session-storage-strategies

Another way of solving multiple server issue, is to use sticky sessions on your load balancer. This is not recommended because of the risc of uneven spread of load.

If you are able to get rid of the need for sessions in your app, I would highly recommend that.

Comment: Usually in the browser settings you can toggle samesite cookie value to test if this is indeed the issue. https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: We can also handle this in the web.conf. See `<sessionstate cookieSameSite="None">` and `<forms cookieSameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />`. Markup may vary between .NET versions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite